# Controlling Instantiations of template in C++

Tags: c++, templates

This statement is from C++ Primer Ver5 P675 Section 16.1.5

> The fact that instantiations are generated when a template is used (§
> 16.1.1, p. 656) means that **the same instantiation may appear in multiple object files**. When two or more separately compiled source
> files use the same template with the same template arguments, there is
> an instantiation of that template in each of those files. In large
> systems, the **overhead of instantiating** the same template in multiple
> files can become significant. Under the new standard, we can avoid
> this overhead through an **explicit instantiation**.

```
// for example, instantion declaration and definition

extern template class Blob<string>; // declaration
template int compare(const int&, const int&); // definition
```

So my question is, is it necessary for the stl template like vector?

For example, if I instantiate/use a `vector<int>` in a.cpp file, should I use something like `extern template vector<int>` in b.cpp file to avoid the overhead?

Comment: This is an optimization, so follow the standard rules. Rule #1: Don't do it. Rule #2: Don't do it now. More seriously, until/unless you're building a system of (at least) a few thousand files, it's probably not worth considering. Keep in mind, all you're optimizing here is build time, not execution speed, so until build time becomes a problem, don't worry about it. And at best, explicit instantiation is going to save something like a few milliseconds per file.